# Django UpdateView generic class

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

How can I access the object passed by the user inside a generic view class?

In template, when the user clicks the link:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'update_peon' pk=item.pk %}"><button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a></td>
```

this goes to urls.py:

```
url(r'^update_peon/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.UpdatePeon.as_view(), name='update_peon'),
```

and my view:

```
   class UpdatePeon(generic.UpdateView):

        login_required = True
        template_name = 'appform/Peons/peon_form.html'
        model = Person
        form_class = PersonForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('view_peons')
```

I would like to access the `item.attr1` or at least `item.pk` inside the class so I could change the model and form accordingly, something like:

```
   class UpdatePeon(generic.UpdateView):

        login_required = True
        template_name = 'appform/Peons/peon_form.html'

        if item['attr1'] == "Attribute1":
            model = model1
            form = model1Form
        else:
             etc

        success_url = reverse_lazy('view_peons')
```

I know how to do it in a normal function based class or even if I rewrite a class based view from scratch but I don't want to do that.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to change the `model` *after* you have the item. The `model` is used to fetch the item.

Comment: @Alasdair well i need to change the model because: Imagine i have a `Parent` Model with name and category as fields. For each `category` i have a child model. User clicks on `edit` and i need to display for him the appropiate `child form` since all child forms are displayed in the same view.

Comment: It sounds like you need to override `get_object` then. There's no point setting `self.model` after you have the item, because `self.model` isn't used after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UpdatePeon(generic.UpdateView):
    if item['attr1'] == "Attribute1":
        model = model1
        form = model1Form
    else:
        ...
```

You can't put code in the class body like this. It runs when the module is loaded, before you have access to the `request`.

You should override a specific method. For example you can override `get_form_class` to change the form class used by the view. Inside the view, you can access the object being updated with `self.object`.

```
class UpdatePeon(generic.UpdateView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.object.pk == 1:
            return MyForm
        else:
            return OtherForm
```

You may find the ccbv website useful for exploring the [update view methods](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/).

Comment: Thx for the response! For the `model` object i should use `get_object` ? I need to dynamically change both the `model` and the `form`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked great but i also need to set the `model` depending on `self.object.pk`. Right now i can only choose the form_class

Comment: `model` is only used to fetch the object. Once `self.get_object()` has been called, there's no point in changing `self.model`. Overriding `get_object` might work. Call `self.object = super(UpdatePeon, self).get_object()` to get the parent model, then use it to replace `self.object` with the instance of the correct model.