# Django generic class view model change

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In generic `UpdateView`, if you need to dynamically change the form depending on the passed object you can use this function (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505034/9751444) answer):

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.object.pk == 1:
        return MyForm
    else:
        return OtherForm
```

Is there a similar function if I want to change the `model`? where model is:

```
class SomeUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):

    login_required = True
    template_name = '...'
    model = SomeModel ## I need it to be dynamic
    form_class = SomeForm 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_url')
```

Comment: This question can help you to override the get_queryset [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707237/use-get-queryset-method-or-set-queryset-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `get_model` method you can override.

Instead, you can override `get_queryset`, and return a queryset of the model you want to use.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if use_my_model():
        return MyModel.objects.all()
    else:
        return OtherModel.objects.all()
```

Or you can override `get_object`, and return the object of the model you want to use.

```
def get_object(self):
    if use_my_model():
        return get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    else:
         return get_object_or_404(OtherModel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: The override worked, thx. I'll try to dig in more so i can understand better but it did work very good.

Answer (score 2):

As described in documentation for [ModelFormMixin.model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.model) you can dynamically compute the queryset your view will work on by overriding [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
def get_queryset(self):

    if any_condition:
        return MyModel.objects.filter(type='foo')
    elif another_condition:
        return AnotherModel.objects.all()
    else:
        return MyModel.objects.all()
```

There is a terrific website to quickly retrieve all attributes of Django class based views. I don't think i'm allowed to advertise here, but you can access it from ccbv.co.uk (I'm not the creator of this website, nor related to it, but I use it almost everyday...).